# trying to implement the uisearchcontroller but its not giving any search result

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

```
 import UIKit

 class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController,  PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {


//approches for uisearchbar
var searchNotes: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
var notesSearchController = UISearchController()
var searchActive: Bool = false


// creating array for holding ojects 



var noteObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
  var v = 0




   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    self.notesSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.notesSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    self.notesSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    // Configure the search controller's search bar
    self.notesSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a user"
    self.notesSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.notesSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    // Set the search controller to the header of the table
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.notesSearchController.searchBar

     print("check")



       }

     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)



    if v == 0 {
        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore()
        //self.fetchAllObjects()

    }
    }


   // fetching data from local datastore and from parse

   func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore(){

      let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sinhgad")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    query.fromLocalDatastore()

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { ( objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {




            let temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray!

            self.noteObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

             self.tableView.reloadData()


        }else {
        print(error!.userInfo)

        }
      }

    }



    func fetchAllObjects(){

     let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sinhgad")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {




            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block:  nil )


            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore()

           // self.tableView.reloadData()


        } else {
        print(error?.userInfo)

         }
      }  
      }





   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



   // MARK: - Table view data source

   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if (self.notesSearchController.active) {
        return self.searchNotes.count
    } else {

    return self.noteObjects.count
    }}


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath      indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterTableViewCell


    if (self.notesSearchController.active && self.searchNotes.count > indexPath.row) {
        // bind data to the search results cell
         let object : PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        cell.MasterTitleLabel?.text = object["Title"] as? String
        cell.MasterTextLabel.text = object["Fstory"] as? String
        cell.MasterTimeLabel.text = object["Time"] as? String
        cell.MasterLocationLabel.text = object["Location"] as? String

        return cell

    } else {
 let object : PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject



    cell.MasterTitleLabel?.text = object["Title"] as? String
    cell.MasterTextLabel.text = object["Fstory"] as? String
    cell.MasterTimeLabel.text = object["Time"] as? String
    cell.MasterLocationLabel.text = object["Location"] as? String



    return cell
    }}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if (self.notesSearchController.active && self.searchNotes.count > 0) {
        // Segue or whatever you want
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openStory", sender: self)

    } else {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openStory", sender: self)
}

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let upcoming: AddNoteTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNoteTableViewController

    if (segue.identifier == "openStory"){


        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        upcoming.object = object

        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

}


@IBAction func btnReload(sender: AnyObject) {

    fetchAllObjects()
   }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete ){

        let object : PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        // the below for deleting the selected cell's object from server's database
       // object.deleteInBackground()

        //the below for deleting the selected cell's object from localstorage
        object.unpinInBackground()


      self.noteObjects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

  }
}
// MARK: - Parse Backend methods

func loadSearchUsers(searchString: String) {

    let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sinhgad")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    // Filter by search string
    query.whereKey("Notes", containsString: searchString)

    self.searchActive = true
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects, error) -> Void in



         if (error == nil) {
            self.searchNotes.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.searchNotes += objects as [PFObject]!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("search query error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
        self.searchActive = false
    }
}

// MARK: - Search Bar Delegate Methods

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    // Force search if user pushes button
    let searchString: String = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
    if (searchString != "") {
        loadSearchUsers(searchString)
    }
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    // Clear any search criteria
    searchBar.text = ""

    // Force reload of table data from normal data source
}



// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Methods

// This function is used along with UISearchResultsUpdating for dynamic search results processing
// Called anytime the search bar text is changed
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    let searchString: String = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
    if (searchString != "" && !self.searchActive) {
        loadSearchUsers(searchString)
    }
}
 }
```

The above code is for retrieving stored objects from parse's server and from local storage and show them in table view.

Everything is working fine but I am trying to implement searchbar for adding searching function into my app. The problem is that when am running the app its showing the searchbar but when interacting with search bar its moving to upside and disappearing and when am typing anything.

I am not getting any search result and in `NSLog` am getting this :

```
  2015-12-03 16:43:48.769 Notes[1015:56944] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UISearchController: 0x7ff2d48165a0>)
```

I know am missing something and its not the right way to achieve that function.

If somebody knows how to do it correctly or what am missing than please let me know , thanks and sorry if the way am asking question is not proper !

i just figured out that my 'searchNotes' var of Pfobject have nothing i mean its empty ! for that i tried

```
    cell.MasterTitleLabel?.text = searchNotes["Title"] as! String
```

but its giving error

```
       cannot subscript  a value of type '[PFObject]' with an index of type 'string'
```

i know its because i declared searchNotes as

```
  searchNotes [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
```

i should do it something like

```
  searchNotes PFObject = PFObject()
```

but when am doing this its giving so many errors please help if somebody's know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't user PFObject directly.

Can you use another class instead of PFObject

```
private class object {

var mTitle : String!
var mStory : String!
var mTime : String!
var mLocation : String!
}

And use your code here 

let obj : object = object()
obj.mTitle = PFObject["title"];
...etc
```